# Drag and Drop. Getting the id where the element is being dragged FROM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble getting the id of the outer div the draggable element is being taken from.

Here is my HTML
http://dev.eteacher.online/taskAssets/cup.jpg'/>

///Droppables ".snap"

```
<div id="0" class='col-word'><p class="letters">c</p></div>
<div id="1" class='col-word snap' style=""><p class="letters">__</p></div>
<div id="2" class='col-word snap' style=""><p class="letters">__</p></div>
```

///Draggables

```
<div id="comparison">
    <div id="v"  class='col-letter'><p class="letters">v</p></div>
    <div id="p"  class='col-letter'><p class="letters">p</p></div>
    <div id="u"  class='col-letter'><p class="letters">u</p></div>
</div>
```

Then I have the important jQuery

```
   var  beh = new Array();
    var beh2 = "";
    var MyVar = "";

    $(".col-letter").draggable({ cursor: 'move', snap: '.snap',
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
            // $(this).data("draggable")
            // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
            // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
            $(this).data("ui-draggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            // return boolean
            return !event;
            // that evaluate like this:
            // return event !== false ? false : true;
        },
        drag: function(event, ui){
                    if($(this).data('droppedin')){
            $(this).data('droppedin').droppable('enable');
            $(this).data('droppedin',null);
            $(this).removeClass( 'dropped' );
             MyVar =  $(this).closest(".col-word").attr("id");   
             alert(MyVar); 
            beh[MyVar] = "";
             alert(beh);
         }
        }
    });
$(".snap").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {    
    var drop_p = $(this).offset();
    var drag_p = ui.draggable.offset();
    var left_end = drop_p.left - drag_p.left;
    var top_end = drop_p.top - drag_p.top ;
    ui.draggable.animate({
        top: '+=' + top_end,
        left: '+=' + left_end
    });
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'dropped' );

   ui.draggable.data('droppedin',$(this));
     $(this).droppable('disable');

}
});


$( ".snap" ).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {

    MyVar = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    beh[MyVar] = ui.draggable.attr('id');
    alert(beh[MyVar] + " " + MyVar);
  //  alert(beh);

    //beh[] = new Array($(this).attr('id'), ui.draggable.attr('id'));
   //alert(beh);
});
```

Basically you can drag divs in and out of the .snap class. I want to get the id of the .snap class when I drag the divs off of the .snap.

I'm having trouble doing this. The closest function is bringing me undefined!

Any ideas?

**EDIT** Goal: The goal is to know which id for each col-letter gets placed on which .snap class.

The way to I thought it out was to have a get request once a button is pressed such that the position and the letter are provided.

For example, if you place id=v on id=1. the get request will enable /1v.

**EDIT 2**

This worked!

```
$(".snap").on("drop", function(event, ui) {
     MyVar = ui.helper.attr('id');
     beh[MyVar] = $(this).attr('id') + ui.helper.attr('id');
     alert(beh[MyVar]);
   });
```

But it makes my join command stop working!

```
  $( "#done" ).click(function(){
        beh2 = beh.join("");
        var link = "/task/fillLetters/response/"+ beh2;
        alert(beh2);
        window.location.replace(link);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().attr('id')`

Comment: This is giving me the parent id of the original parent-id. Not where it's being dragged from being already dropped elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, it's the original parent where it's being dragged from?

Comment: .col-letters is in a different starting div. See edit. THe .col-letters are dragged from #comparison parent div. Into the .snap div. my drag function works only after it's been dragged into .snap and you reattempt to drag the element out of .snap. I want the id of the .snap it's being dragged out of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/bksL352s/

```js
var beh = new Array();
var beh2 = "";
var MyVar = "";

$(".col-letter").draggable({
  cursor: 'move',
  snap: '.snap',
  revert: function(event, ui) {

    $(this).data("ui-draggable").originalPosition = {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    };

    return !event;

  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).data('droppedin')) {
      $(this).data('droppedin').droppable('enable');
      $(this).data('droppedin', null);
      $(this).removeClass('dropped');
      MyVar = $(this).attr('data-dropped-Id');
      alert(MyVar);
      beh[MyVar] = "";
      alert(beh);

    }
  }
});
$(".snap").droppable({
  hoverClass: 'hovered',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var drop_p = $(this).offset();
    var drag_p = ui.draggable.offset();
    var left_end = drop_p.left - drag_p.left;
    var top_end = drop_p.top - drag_p.top;
    ui.draggable.animate({
      top: '+=' + top_end,
      left: '+=' + left_end
    });
    ui.draggable.addClass('dropped');

    ui.draggable.data('droppedin', $(this));
    $(this).droppable('disable');

  }
});


$(".snap").on("drop", function(event, ui) {
  MyVar = event.target.getAttribute('id');
  beh[MyVar] = ui.draggable.attr('id');
  ui.draggable.attr('data-dropped-Id', $(this).attr('id'));
  alert(beh[MyVar] + " " + MyVar);

});
```

```css
.col-letter {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px 0;
  transition: background ease-In .2s;
}
.col-word.snap {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #C5C5C5;
}
.dropped p {
  background: #CDDC39 !important;
}
.dropped {
  border-color: #000 !important;
}
.col-word.snap p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.col-letter p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="0" class='col-word'>
  <p class="letters">c</p>
</div>
<div id="1" class='col-word snap' style="">
  <p class="letters">__</p>
</div>
<div id="2" class='col-word snap' style="">
  <p class="letters">__</p>
</div>


<div id="comparison">
  <div id="v" class='col-letter'>
    <p class="letters">v</p>
  </div>
  <div id="p" class='col-letter'>
    <p class="letters">p</p>
  </div>
  <div id="u" class='col-letter'>
    <p class="letters">u</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 2):

The following will get you the id of both the dragged element and dropped element..

```
   $(".snap").on("drop", function(event, ui) {
       MyVar = $(this).attr('id');
       beh[MyVar] = ui.helper.attr('id');
       alert(MyVar + " " + beh[MyVar]);
   });
```

Same goes with your drag function use

```
MyVar = $(this).attr('id'); //to get your id
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2a6tur6w/3/

Comment: @JPFoster please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, or leave feedback. Thanks

Comment: This worked! But one issue that came out of it was that my command beh.join() no longer works.I also changed some of your code, for practicality for my code.      code // MyVar = ui.helper.attr('id');
     beh[MyVar] = $(this).attr('id') + ui.helper.attr('id'); //Code  See edit

Answer (score 0):

You are after `event.target` in your `'drop'` handler...

```
$(".snap").on("drop", function(event, ui) {  
    MyVar = $(event.target).attr('id');   // here
    beh[MyVar] = ui.draggable.attr('id');
    alert(beh[MyVar] + " " + MyVar);
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zoa3wL0n/

Comment: Yes I am. But after it's dropped. If I drop it back to the original position, it does not reset.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you store the value with the onclick handler and then retrieve it when you 'drop'?

```
var draggedItem 
$(".snap").on("drag", function(event, ui) {
 draggedItem = $(this).attr('id');
});

$(".snap").on("drop", function(event, ui) {
  alert(draggedItem) 
});
```